# Minimize off-screen rendering when using CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, core-animation

Pretty standard setup: VC view has top corners rounded via CAShapeLayer with UIBezierPath, like this:

```
UIBezierPath *cornerPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRoundedRect:self.view.bounds
                                                 byRoundingCorners:UIRectCornerTopLeft | UIRectCornerTopRight
                                                       cornerRadii:CGSizeMake(4, 4)];
CAShapeLayer *maskLayer = [CAShapeLayer layer];
maskLayer.frame = self.view.bounds;
maskLayer.path = cornerPath.CGPath;
self.view.layer.mask = maskLayer;
```

While this works, it leads to the *whole* view being rendered offscreen, surely there should be a way to at least minimize that rendering to corners, or even get rid of it?

Comment: have you tried to add the shapelayer as a sublayer instead of a mask?

Comment: Masking generally leads to off-screen rendering. If the mask is big but the masked area is small this could be costly. What content is visible behind the masked content?

Comment: Then just add black "inverse" corner cut-outs on top of everything.